# Select nth-child of high level selector

Tags: html, css

How do I use the pseudo-class `nth-child` of a selector that is not the immediate parent of said child?

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

#main .test:nth-child(even) {
  background: green;
}
```

**JS**

```
// doesnt work
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  $('#main').append('<div><div class="test"></div></div>')
}
// works
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  $('#main').append('<div class="test"></div>')
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9yq0bhjk/)**

Comment: I know you're supposed to use nth-of-type if you want even or odd, but not sure why it's not working. Why not just make the parent div the one with the background?

Comment: The :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth child of its **parent**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select the `.test` div, you need to select every even child of `#main`, then select the `.test` within.

**CSS**

```
#main div:nth-child(even) .test {
  background: green;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9yq0bhjk/2/)**

Comment: It is frustrating because I can do `#main .test{  padding-right:100px; }` which selects all `.test` within `#main`, but I cannot apply similar logic using this class?

Comment: unfortunately, there is no such thing as "nth-of-class", you have to work with nth-child or nth-of-type and keep the parent-child structure.. only workaround would be jquery, which is not the best idea

Answer (score 1):

As you have two different kind of structures in your html, use different selectors for styling

```
#main .test:nth-child(even) ,
#main div:nth-child(even) > .test{
  background: green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9yq0bhjk/4/